# SQL in Power Bi Explanation

Tags: graph, powerbi, dax

I just started my first co op, was given a SQL task, and needed help understanding the code.

```
_Bridge_% = 
VAR __avail__ = SUM([MaxCapacityLbs]) + SUM([UpstreamRateLossLbs])
RETURN
SWITCH(MIN(TRSp_Area_Bridge[Lookup]),
    "theo", BLANK(),
    "a", BLANK(),
    "b", BLANK(),
    "c", BLANK(),
    "c2", BLANK(),
    "c21", BLANK(),
    "avl", 1,
    "d", SUM([Loss_d]) / __avail__,
    "d22", SUM([Loss_d22]) / __avail__,
    "e", SUM([Loss_e]) / __avail__,
    "e1", SUM([Loss_e1]) / __avail__,
    "e2", BLANK(),
    "e3", BLANK(),
    "e5", SUM([Loss_e5]) / __avail__,
    "f", SUM([Loss_f]) / __avail__,
    "f11", SUM([Loss_f11]) / __avail__,
    "f130", SUM([Loss_f130]) / __avail__,
    "f131", SUM([Loss_f131]) / __avail__,
    "f132", SUM([Loss_f132]) / __avail__,
    "f14", SUM([Loss_f14]) / __avail__,
    "f2", SUM([Loss_f2]) / __avail__,
    "f3", SUM([Loss_f3]) / __avail__,
    "f4", SUM([Loss_f4]) / __avail__,
    "g1", SUM([Loss_g1]) / __avail__,
    "g23", SUM([Loss_g23]) / __avail__,
    "g24", SUM([Loss_g24]) / __avail__,
    "g25", SUM([Loss_g25]) / __avail__,
    "g26", SUM([Loss_g26]) / __avail__,
    "g3", SUM([Loss_g3]) / __avail__,
    "i", BLANK()
```

I have been looking at it for a day and am a little confused because they are using a program called Power Bi which I've never used before; Which uses some different ways to store algorithms and smaller segments of arithmetic. The code is used to untimely create a waterfall graph but it seems to me, there is a lot of unused variables in the switch. The graph at most has 13 bars which is less than the number of switches.

If I had to pinpoint the biggest reason of confusion, it would be the **avail** variable. I don't understand what the `/ __avail__` does.

If you need more information just ask I'll be happy to add it. Thanks.

Comment: I hope this helps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/dax-operator-reference

Comment: Check out this article as well:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/best-practices/dax-variables '___avail___' is a declared variable here, defined on line 2 as the sum of the maxcapacitylbs measure + the sum of the upstream ratelosslbs measure.